# Incremental JQuery Function On Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a javascript or jQuery function (but open to other ideas) that will echo the number of html values based upon this php function.

```
<?php if( have_rows('SECTION') ): $i = 0;
    while ( have_rows('SECTION') ) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
        <div id='NAME-<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php the_sub_field('OBJECT'); ?></div>
        <div id='NAME-<?php echo $i; ?>-p'><?php the_sub_field('OBJECT-2'); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile;
    else :
endif; ?>
```

The basic jQuery function that I'm using is this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#NAME-1').click(function () {
        $('#NAME-1-p').stop().fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Right now I just repeat that function over and over and replace the number consecutively so there ends up being more functions than actual objects on the page. This is because the info being called by the php function can range from 1 - 20.

Looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Use a class instead of a bunch of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class and then locate the second div relative to what was clicked:

```
<?php if( have_rows('SECTION') ): $i = 0;
    while ( have_rows('SECTION') ) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
        <div class='clickable'><?php the_sub_field('OBJECT'); ?></div>
        <div><?php the_sub_field('OBJECT-2'); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile;
    else :
endif; ?>

$(function () {
    $('.clickable').click(function () {
        $(this).next().stop().fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: What about in the case where they aren't right next to each other?

Comment: If they are always in the same relative position you can alter the code that locates your sub element.  If the sub element varies you could give it a class and use jquery find.